# Replace *variable* text but keep case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace some text in a javascript **variable** without losing case, ie.

`"MAT" ==> "MATch string in db"` instead of `"Mat" ==> "match string in db"`

Right now I'm doing this (doesn't keep the original case):

```
var user_str = $("#user-input").val();
var db_match = db_match.replace(new RegExp(user_str, "ig") , '<span class="u b match">' + user_str + '</span>');
```

I found cases where people needed to replace static text, but in my case I need to replace variable content instead.

Obviously this doesn't work either:

```
var user_str = $("#user-input").val();
db_match = db_match.replace(/(user_str)/ig, "<span class=u b match>$1</span>");
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Use a group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) and build the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```js
    var str = "test";
    var text = "Test this";
    var re = new RegExp("(" + str + ")","gi");
    console.log(text.replace(re, "<span>$1</span>"))  //"<span>Test</span> this"
```